JMS queue and Weblogic .Net client issues with load balancer

I am currently working with a .NET 8 application that utilizes a queue push mechanism to send data to a JMS Queue using WebLogic.Messaging library (version 1.3.4).

While the functionality performs as expected when transmitting data to standard servers, I encounter issues when attempting to send data to a Load Balancer.


Here is the error that I'm getting.
Exception Message : Problem creating context
WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.TransportException: Failed to connect using URL <t3://domain_url:port_number>

Here is my JMSQueueManager class which handles data transfer.
public JMSQueueManager(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<JMSQueueManager> logger)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _logger = logger;

    _JMSUrl = _configuration.GetSection("JMSDetails").GetSection("JMSUrl").Value ?? string.Empty;
    _JMSConnectionFactory = _configuration.GetSection("JMSDetails").GetSection("JMSConnectionFactory").Value;
    _JMSUserName = _configuration.GetSection("JMSDetails").GetSection("JMSUserName").Value;
    _JMSPassword = _configuration.GetSection("JMSDetails").GetSection("JMSPassword").Value;
}

private IContext CreateJMSContext()
{
    try
    {
        if (_context == null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"CreateJMSContext() entered.");
            IDictionary<string, Object> paramMap = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            paramMap[Context.PROVIDER_URL] = _JMSUrl ?? string.Empty;
            paramMap[Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL] = _JMSUserName ?? string.Empty;
            paramMap[Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS] = _JMSPassword ?? string.Empty;
            _context = ContextFactory.CreateContext(paramMap);
            _logger.LogInformation($"CreateJMSContext() - context created.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Error occurred while creating JMS context to JMS Queue. Exception Message : {ex.Message} || Stack Trace : {ex.StackTrace}");
        throw ex;
    }
    return _context;
}

I'm kind of blocked right now due to this and Any help would be really appreciated.
thanks!
